# Delete a database record and associated image

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of photos like this:

```
photo_id, photo_url, user_id
```

When I want to delete a photo, I need to delete the row in the table and the photo on the server. So to do this, I need to do 2 queries:

1. A `SELECT` query to return the photo's url and delete it with `unlink()`
2. a `DELETE` query to delete the row in the table

Is a simpler way to do this, perhaps using only one query?

Comment: It seems like the photo is physical file not stored in the database.  If that's the case, then you will have to delete it in two locations (meaning a select query and a delete statement), I see no easier way to accomplish this.  If the photo itself was stored in the DB (in a BLOB column), then it would be trivially simple (the delete statement itself would suffice).

Comment: @Chad: As far as I can tell, that's true - probably the answer to this question.

Comment: I don't think `SELECT * FROM DELETE ...` is valid syntax in MySQL, but that would be the only "more efficient way" I can think of. If you google `SELECT FROM DELETE` you can see it exists in some places.

Comment: I remember learning mysql and wondering similar, as in: "Can I delete a record, and then have mysql tell me what the photo_id was if the delete succeeds?"

Answer (score 2):

Your way the best way to do this....How can it be simpler....

Also, if your photos use ids then you may just delete the row instead of selecting the query to return to the photos URL. then if this is successful proceed with deleting the thumbnail